# AWS API gateway with seperate environments- Production and staging

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have separate environment for production and staging in aws API gateway.Staging gateway can access staging DB and staging lambda function.But we are using the following code inside DBUtil database connectivity.

```
private static String endpoint="testURL.amazonaws.com:3306";
private static String endPointUserName="master";
private static String endPointPassword="1234";
private static String endPointDBName="appTest_staging";
```

And while moving to production the database is still pointing to staging DB.Can anyone suggest me the best way to find the environment and choose the db based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stage variables - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html